# How to execute function in a specific thread from threadpool

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have a messages queue, and thread pool.
Massive messages amount are being sent to queue.

In my threads (from the pool) I'm taking each message and pushing into the thread in-memory list using `ThreadLocal<List<...>>`.

My goal is on the X message to do some processing such as save to the DB,...

But,
I want as well, every Y seconds to do the same processing.

So, or we reached to X messages or Y seconds passed - then do processing.

What I've done is to start the timer on the first message and on fired to do the processing. The processing will stop the timer incase it was done by X messages.

My problem is with my timer that I create in the thread. The callback function naturally is being raised in a new thread and I don't have access to `ThreadLocal-List`.

I'm trying to avoid locking, syncing, and such - this is why i use ThreadLocal for my lists and timers.

Is there any elegant way to do what I wished for?

Maybe in the callback of my timer to execute the processing method with the same thread from the thread pool who created the timer?

--EDIT--
We use AWS SQS for the queue.
We fetch the message using SQSListener of spring cloud.
Our processing is basically saving to the DB.
We run on many pods (Kubernetes).

2 issues we faced:

1. Performing a simple Update on the DB every message in each thread of the `SQSListener` in each pod will be inefficient, therefor we thought about doing a bulk update which is faster - we tested it.
2. `SQSListener` creates max 10 threads to fetch the messages. It won't fetch another message till the thread is done. Therefor we wanted to "kicK" the message to a new thread fast, so `SQSListener` thread will fetch a new one and we would be able to collect more message for the bulk update.

Comment: I'd expect a ThreadLocal only to be valid for a single execution of any message processing, then wiped - in other words: If you use ThreadPools, don't rely on persistent ThreadLocals. If you want those, don't use pools. If you make sure that a message is only processed by a single thread, you often don't even need locking, syncing etc., so I don't understand where your issue is (apart from the arbitrary decision to look for the same thread over and over. Don't do that)

Comment: I do not process the messages in the threads but only collect them - this way i can continue fetching messages and fast. They will be processed after 1000 messages collected, or after 5 seconds - the first from both. I'm using this method in order to do bulk update in the DB.. I have millions of users sending messages constantly. Would not want to update the DB every single message. Once the messages are processed and well processed, I'm removing them from the original Queue. If something bad happend, then they will be back in the queue after 30 seconds automatically and will be re-fetched.

Comment: Don't use `ThreadLocal`. ThreadLocal only makes sense if it's a `static` variable, and you should get out of the habit of using static variables. Code with static variables is hard to maintain, and hard to test. Also, try to avoid writing code that has to be called by a certain thread. If a thing needs to be done, it should be OK for any thread to do it.

Comment: P.S., the reason why `ThreadLocal` even exists is because if you have old, single-threaded library code that has a lot of `static` variables, then making them `ThreadLocal` can be a shortcut to making a "thread-safe" version of it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Any good Ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: Why retrieve x messages and/or y seconds? What is the rationale why not just process the messages as the come in? Why queue them again (because that is what you are basically doing) and then again process them one by one? I don't really see the benefit here, it could even slow things down. Feels like you are optimizing something without even having measured that it is a problem or not. We process millions of messages from multiple topics and we just process them one by one. Why queue 1000 process them and have 999 good ones and the last one fails.

Comment: One thing that came to mind is that you can use Spring Batch to read x messages and do the commit (and have proper error handling). It has readers for jms, kafka etc. and you can set the chunk size. You would have a long live job. Another option is to manually do tx management and count the number of messages processed and then do a commit. Although I would first make it work with single messages and actually see if it is really a performance issue before optimizing.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the Help. Processing it is not so much but saving to the DB the new state the clients sent as a message. We use AWS SQS as queue, and use spring cloud for fetching the messages. As we saw spring is creating 10 threads for fetching messages and we created those threads in order to let free its threads to fetch more messages and not process/save each to the DB in the fetch message thread. On top we have many pods running. When each message in each thread in each pod will do simple update in the DB, instead of bulk update it is very much performance issue. It was tested by us

Comment: You can reduce the number of threads. Make sure you have investigated properly and that you are solving the right problem, instead of introducing complexity which appears to solve the problem. Because as stated we have more or less the same setup without issues (reading from kafka with multiple threads and pods to store in db). That all being said as stated you can use Spring Batch which will read x messages from a topic/queue and process them, instead of trying to build your own.

Comment: We did investigate and saw that simple update of DB on every message is slow, compares to bulk update which is much faster. This is why we would like somehow to collect messages. But we don't want to say every X messages to perform the DB update because we can't guarantee this X all the time. So we've added the time limit. I will check out the Spring Batch. Thanks so far

Comment: If you upgrade to Spring Cloud AWS 3.0, you can set maxMessagesPerPoll to 1000 and the framework will make concurrent calls to SQS to try to fulfill that. You can then use a List<> in your listener method to fetch the list of messages and process in batch.

Comment: Docs if you’re interested: https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-RC2/reference/html/index.html#batch-processing

Comment: due to Vulnerability issues we can't yet upgrade from S-Boot 2.. But Thanks for the suggestion. it will definitely help us in the future